# How to bring program to front using python

Tags: python, qt

I would like to force my python app to the front if a condition occurs. I'm using Kubuntu & QT3.1

I've tried setActiveWindow(), but it only flashes the task bar in KDE.

I think Windows has a function bringwindowtofront() for VB.

Is there something similar for KDE?

Answer (score 4):

Check if KWin is configured to prevent focus stealing.

There might be nothing wrong with your code -- but we linux people don't like applications bugging us when we work, so stealing focus is kinda frowned upon, and difficult under some window managers.

Comment: Not just Linux guys don't like windows stealing focus!

Comment: =) but can you do anything about it on non-X11 systems?

Comment: BTW, I'm making this action optional + its just a personal project so the HIG won't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using those 3 (in this order) on your window instead of only `setActiveWindow`?

```
show()
raise() # this might be raiseW() in Python
setActiveWindow()
```

Answer (score 1):

It works!

```
show()
raiseW()
setActiveWindow() #in that sequence
```

*plus* KWin config change to force focus steal prevention.

Thanks for the help.